# C# error logging to file

Tags: c#, logging, try-catch

I'm looking to implement a simple error log in my program. I've tried simply using try/catch and writing the error message to a text file in the catch. It works, but I'd then need to encapsulate every single method in a try/catch.

Is there are simple way to do this? Any way to simply redirect error messages to a text file, for example?

Comment: First you should tell what is your program web/win forms or ..., also the question is too broad for SO.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Aspect Oriented Programming. Also wrapping everything in try-catch seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: You must use `try/catch` to handle exception (thus logging *handled* exceptions). It is also recommended to handle *unhandled* exceptions (use search, don't forget to specify wpf/winforms). As far as I know there is no way to automatically log handled exception (you can easily do it for unhandled), but there is nothing bad in adding just one row into each `catch`, like `Log.Add(e, ...);`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Application.ThreadException event

[LInk to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=IT-IT&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)